# undefined method `cliq_requests' for nil:NilClass

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, crud

I keep getting this annoying error consistently and I cannot solve it. I recently posted a question on the same topic and got no productive help.

I want users to request to join a group. **Cliqs = Groups**. All of my console tests seem correct, but I cannot seem to find a solution to my problem. The association is showing up, but I can't seem to get the update/accept method to run.

This is driving me crazy! How do I fix this?

Here is my code:

My Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :uploads

has_one :owned_cliq, foreign_key: 'owner_id', class_name: 'Cliq', dependent: :destroy

has_many :cliq_memberships, dependent: :destroy
has_many :cliqs, through: :cliq_memberships

has_many :cliq_requests, dependent: :destroy
...
end


class Cliq < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'

has_many :cliq_memberships, dependent: :destroy
has_many :members, through: :cliq_memberships, source: :user

has_many :cliq_requests, dependent: :destroy                                #cliq_request_sender
has_many :pending_members, through: :cliq_requests, source: :user, foreign_key: 'user_id'
end


class CliqRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
#from
belongs_to :user
#to
belongs_to :cliq

#validate :not_member

#validate :not_pending

def accept
    cliq.members << pending_member
    destroy
end
end
```

My controller:

```
class CliqRequestsController < ApplicationController

def index
    #incoming
    #@cliq_requests_received = CliqRequest.where(cliq: cliq)
    #outgoing
    #@cliq_requests_sent = current_user.cliq_requests
end

def show
end

def create
    cliq = Cliq.find_by(params[:id])
    @cliq_request = current_user.cliq_requests.new(cliq: cliq)


    if @cliq_request.save
        redirect_to current_user #change to cliqs/cliq path later
    else
        redirect_to cliq_path
    end 
end

def update
    @cliq = Cliq.find_by(id: params[:cliq_id])
    @cliq_request = @cliq.cliq_requests.find_by(id: params[:id])
    @cliq_request.accept
end

def destroy
    @cliq_request.destroy
end
end
```

My View:

```
<h1><%= @cliq.name %></h1>

<%= link_to 'Request to join Cliq', '/cliqs/:cliq_id/cliq_requests', :method => :post %>

<% @cliq_members.each do |cliq_member| %>
<ul><%= link_to cliq_member.username, user_path(cliq_member) %></ul>
<% end %>

<% if @current_user = @cliq.owner %>
<% @cliq.pending_members.each do |pending_member| %>
<ul><%= link_to pending_member.username, user_path %>
<%= link_to "Accept", "/cliqs/:cliq_id/cliq_requests/:id/", :method => :put %>
<%= link_to "Deny", "/cliqs/:cliq_id/cliq_requests/:id/", :method => :delete %>
</ul>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

My Routes:

```
resources :cliqs do
  resources :cliq_requests
end
```

Comment: At which line you are getting that error?

Comment: Line 32: in update on the CliqRequestsController. Where it says " @cliq_request = @cliq.cliq_requests.find_by(id: params[:id])".

Comment: It should be of note that I've tried numerous configurations with this particular action to no avail. I've also tried a number of different routes, as well.

Comment: Can you post your routes?

Comment: Sure. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines appear malformed:

```
<%= link_to 'Request to join Cliq', '/cliqs/:cliq_id/cliq_requests', :method => :post %>
<%= link_to "Accept", "/cliqs/:cliq_id/cliq_requests/:id/", :method => :put %>
<%= link_to "Deny", "/cliqs/:cliq_id/cliq_requests/:id/", :method => :delete %>
```

I recommend you use path helpers [e.g. `cliq_cliq_request_path(cliq, cliq_request)` if you are using resourceful routing]. You can use rake routes for help.  If you are seeing things like `:cliq_id` and and `:id` in your development.log or test.log as part of the URLs that are hit, those should instead be numbers.  You can also interpolate the strings yourself (e.g. `"/cliqs/#{cliq_id}/cliq_requests/#{cliq_request.id}"`) but this is usually more typing and certainly more fragile over time.

One of your problems may be that you are looping through a list of pending member names, which doesn't have all the data you need to form the link correctly.  So your update action may be working fine, but you may not be passing it the right data.

Also this line:

```
if @current_user = @cliq.owner
```

is an assignment, and so will always return true.  Presumably you mean `==`

Comment: So the request "create" action worked. All of the necessary data was persisted to the database(cliq_id, user_id, and cliq_request_id). Why does it not work for the update/destroy method?

Comment: I don't think you've supplied the code that invokes the `create` method.  Usually that is in a _form partial.

Comment: Try adding a `puts params[:id]` or `raise params[:id]` in your update method, and look in your log or your web browser.  If it says a number, this answer is wrong.  If it says :id, these are the kinds of changes you'll need to make in your loop.  (I'd recommend looping through cliq_requests, rather than pending members, since it's easy to get a user from a cliq_request.)

Comment: It's referenced in the "Request to join Cliq" path.

Comment: Your create action probably isn't working either (just in a less explosive way) - I bet all your requests are being creating with null cliq

Comment: No. The Cliq_id of the selected Cliq persists with create.